# IEnumerable<T> from Enumerable.FromRange().Select() vs ToList()

Tags: c#, list, pass-by-reference, ienumerable

This really stumped me, as I expected 'pass by reference' behavior.  I expected this code to print "5,5,5", but instead it prints "7,7,7".

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> list = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => new MyObj { Name = 7 });
Alter(list);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',',list.Select(x => x.Name.ToString())));
Console.ReadLine();

void Alter(IEnumerable<MyObj> list)
{
    foreach(MyObj obj in list)
    {
        obj.Name = 5;
    }
}

class MyObj
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Whereas this prints "7,7,7" as expected.

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> list = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => new MyObj { Name = 7 }).ToList();
Alter(list);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',',list.Select(x => x.Name.ToString())));
Console.ReadLine();

void Alter(IEnumerable<MyObj> list)
{
    foreach(MyObj obj in list)
    {
        obj.Name = 5;
    }
}

class MyObj
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously this is a simplified version of the actual code I was writing.  This feels a lot more like behavior I've run into with a property that instantiates a new instance of an object.  Here I understand why I would get a new instance every time I reference `Mine`.

```
public MyObj Mine => new MyObj();
```

I was just very surprised to see this behavior in the above code, where it feels more like I've "locked in" the enumerated objects.  Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: This isn't about pass-by-reference. (There isn't any in your code.) It's about lazy evaluation. Each time you iterate over `Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => new MyObj { Name = 7 })`, it will create a new sequence of objects. This makes your use of the name `list` unhelpful, because it's *not* a list - it's a lazily-evaluated sequence. When you call `ToList()`, the returned value *is* a reference to a list - it's materialized. I suggest you search for tutorials on "LINQ lazy evaluation" or "deferred execution".

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'll have to remember the term "deferred execution" in the future.

Answer (score 3):

`Select` produces an object that has [lazy evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-5.0#remarks). This means all steps are executed on demand.

So, when this line gets executed:

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> list = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => new MyObj { Name = 7 });
```

no `MyObj` instance is created yet - only the enumerable that has all the information to compute what you've indicated.

When you call `Alter`, this gets executed during iteration via `foreach` and all objects get `5` assigned to their properties.

But when you print it, everything gets executed again here:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',',list.Select(x => x.Name.ToString())));
```

So during execution of `string.Join`, brand new `MyObj` instances are created with `new MyObj { Name = 7 }` and printed.

Answer (score 2):

> This feels a lot more like behavior I've run into with a property that instantiates a new instance of an object

Your feelings are correct

As a preface to this answer I want to point out that in C# we can store methods inside variables like we can store data:

```
var method = () => new MyObj();
```

The `() => new MyObj()` is the "method"; it has no name, takes no parameters and returns a new MyObj. We don't actually refer to it as a method, we tend to call it a lambda, but for all intents and purposes it behaves like what you're familiar with as "a method":

```
public MyObj SomeName(){
    return new MyObj();
}
```

You can probably pick out the common parts- the compiler guesses the return type, provides a name for it internally because we don't care and when it's a single statement that produces a value, the compiles fills in the `return` keyword for us too. It's a very compact method logic.

So, back to this variable called `method`:

```
var method = () => new MyObj();
```

You could run it like:

```
var myObj = method.Invoke();
```

You could even remove the Invoke word and just write `method()`, but I'll leave Invoke in for now, for clarity. When invoked the method will run, return a new MyObj data and that data would be stored in `myObj`..

So, most times when we code, a variable stores data but sometimes it stores a method, and this is handy..

---

When you make a LINQ Select it requires you to give it a method that it will run every time the resulting enumerable is enumerated:

```
var enumerable = new []{1,2,3}.Select(x => new MyObj());
```

*It doesn't run the method `x => new MyObj()` you give at the time you call Select*, it doesn't generate any data; it just stores the method for later

Every time you loop over (enumerate) this it will run that method (`x => new MyObj()`) up to 3 times - I say up to, because you don't have to fully enumerate but if you do, there are 3 elements in the array so the enumeration can cause at most 3 invocations of the method.

LINQ Select doesn't run the method and grab the data - it effectively creates a collection of data-providing methods rather than a collection of data

Conceptually it's like Select produces you an array of full of methods:

```
var enumerable = new[]{
  () => new MyObj(),
  () => new MyObj(),
  () => new MyObj()
};
```

You could enumerate this and run these methods yourself:

```
foreach(var method in enumerable)
  method.Invoke();
```

Your Alter() ran the enumeration (did a loop), got each new object returned from each method, modified it, then it was thrown away. Conceptually your Alter method did this:

```
foreach(var method in enumerable)
  method.Invoke().Name = 5;
```

The method was run, a new MyObj was made with some default value for Name, then Name was changed to 5, then the object data was thrown away

After your Alter was done with you enumerated it again, new objects were made again because the methods were run again, the Name was of course unaltered - new object, no changes. Nothing here is geared up to remember the data being generated; the only thing that is remembered is the list of methods that generate the data

---

When you put a ToList() on the end, that's different - ToList internally enumerates the enumerable, causes the methods that generate the objects to be run but critically *it stashes the resulting objects in a list* and gives you the list of objects. Instead of being a collection of methods that provides values, it's a collection of values that you can alter.

It's like it does this:

```
var r = new List<MyObj>();

foreach(var method in enumerable)
  r.Add(method.Invoke());

return r;
```

This means you get a list of *data* back (not a list of methods that provide data), and if you then loop ovet this list you're altering data that is stored in the list, rather than running methods, altering the returned value and throwing it away

Comment: A lambda expression is not a method; it's a way of creating an (anonymous) _function_.

Comment: And when you were in early grades of school your teacher will have told you you can't take the root of a negative number. All teaching is a graduated stepping of building up understanding by linking concepts back to something that is already understood. If you sea change everything including the terminology, that's not a learning curve, it's a cliff. There will be plenty of time to learn the "by the way this is called a.." once the understanding of what is going on is appreciated

Comment: I see your point, but why assume that OP is more familiar with the term "method" than "function"? A method is a specific type of function, and generally one would learn the latter term before the former. Furthermore, having SO awash with incorrect terminology is counterproductive to those coming here to learn.

Comment: I was starting from the base of "person knows some C# but was relatively surprised by/recently worked out that a property that returns a `new X` doesn't remember anything"; to me, that level would be "properties are data, methods do actions" - For the education systems I'm used to I don't think we start out calling anything a *function* in C# - they're methods, and other teminology is fed in later

Comment: Thanks everyone for being so helpful.  I really appreciate how willing to help everyone in this industry is.  Explanations from a variety of different perspectives often have a way of helping more people understand a concept that wouldn't have been accessible to everyone otherwise.